# Navigation Drawer setItemChecked() does not do anything

Tags: android, position, navigation-drawer

Does anyone have an idea why the setItemChecked() function doesn't work for my below example:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            int pos = position;

                   ...

            default:
                break;
            }
            listView.setItemChecked(pos, true);
            setTitle(titles[pos]);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listviewLayout);
        }
    }
```

In all examples I've seen so far, the setItemChecked is done inside the DrawerItemClickListener method. But for some reason it does not want to work. I've tried to put it inside onCreate() or onResume(), but still no result.

I tested for simple listView, and it seems it doesn't work there either. Any suggestions ?

Code for my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Account account = this.items.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
        viewHolder.textViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        viewHolder.imageViewImage = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add on Your drawer item layout `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"`

Comment: @marioosh It seems it doesn't want to work in any way. I've tried all the examples from all the replies here separately, then combined but with no luck whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

It almost doesn't matter where you call `setItemChecked()`. Are you using custom `ListView` views?

If your answer is yes, you have to specify selectors for `ListView` items.

This might be your drawer's `ListView` item:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/drawer_item_text_view"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/drawer_list_item_background"/>
```

Your item's background (`R.drawable.drawer_list_item_background`) must be specified as selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_menu_active" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_menu_active" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_menu_active" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_menu_normal" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

`R.drawable.bg_menu_active`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

`R.drawable.bg_menu_normal`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

After this done, you are able to set chosen item as checked and highlight it somehow.

Comment: I've pasted your code exactly, but the result is the same. In the java code, where do I have to set the item checked ? Or do i have to do something more than just setItemChecked ?

Comment: Post code of your adapter and how are you setting it.

Comment: I posted it in the question.